# converting "November 19 2019, 12:00 PM" to "2019-11-19T12:00" in python

Tags: python

I'm working on a python project where I'm getting the following variable from a third party service as an example `var = "November 19 2019, 12:00 PM"` and I need to convert it to  `var = "2019-11-19T12:00"` in order to send it to google calendar API request in python

since I'm new to python I know there must be a better way but what I got so far to extract the month is :

Comment: look at .strftime() https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
from datetime import datetime
month_map = {'January': 1, 'February': 2, 'March': 3, 'April': 4, 'May': 5, 'June': 6, 'July': 7, 'August': 8, 'September': 9, 'October': 10, 'November': 11, 'December': 12}
s = "November 19 2019, 12:00 AM"
date_time_list = s.split(' ')
month = month_map[date_time_list[0]]
date = date_time_list[1]
year = date_time_list[2][:4]
hour_min_list = date_time_list[3].split(':')
hour = hour_min_list[0]
if date_time_list[4] == 'PM' and int(hour) != 12:
    hour = str(int(hour) + 12)
if date_time_list[4] == 'AM' and int(hour) == 12:
    hour = '00'
minutes = hour_min_list[1]

iso_format = datetime(int(year), int(month), int(date), int(hour), int(minutes)).isoformat()
print(iso_format)
```

A shorter implementation:

```
from datetime import datetime
s = "November 19 2019, 12:00 AM"
d = datetime.strptime(s, "%B %d %Y, %I:%M %p")
print(d.isoformat())
```